# Ubuntu install CD hangs at 5 red dots while booting

Tags: 12.04, installation, bios, fedora

I put the disk in for 12.04, go to the Bios, and I boot off the disk, it works until the 5 dots go red when it is ready to load the desktop and it just hangs. Worked before when I had windows and I installed Ubuntu over it. I went to Fedora because it looked cool, but I want to go back so I can run my Minecraft server. Any help? I really want to install Ubuntu again.

- Dell Inspiron 1300
- Currently has Fedora 17 KDE installed as primary operating system
- Gets stuck finding the b43-phy0. ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" Not found
- b43-phy0. ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode5.fw" Not found.
- b43-phy0. ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.

**helpfull things**

@J.Naw Did you do "Check disc for defects" on the USB flash drive as well? This applies to USB drives as well as CD/DVD media, and there can be systematic problems that cause multiple downloads to be corrupted or multiple writes to fail

@J.Naw It's unlikely to be caused by Fedora, at least not directly (there would have to be some bug in Ubuntu that made it freeze when it looks at something in the Fedora system). How did you install Ubuntu before? What version did you install--was it this one? Also, please still do "Check disc for defects" on the machine you want to install on because (1) that can reveal problems with the machine as well as the installation media, and (2) the media might really be bad, and just working on other machines with hardware not requiring the corrupted files to be used

@J.Naw Yes, the text-based alternate install CD might work. At this point though, as izx had suggested to me in chat, you might want to press Escape (or F2) when you first see the splash screen with the dots (even before everything stops). That will reveal the messages "behind" it

well there you go, one bug for ubuntu to fix. Lets get to work.

Answer (score 4):

Most often this happens because you have a bad disc. This is especially likely if you've already installed the same version of Ubuntu on this machine before, and didn't have that problem.

The disc could have been damaged, or it could have started out bad (for example, due to a bad ISO image).

- [Check it for defects](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html) on the machine you want to install it on. (That way, the disc gets checked, and so does the computer/drive's ability to read it.)
- If that fails, make sure to [MD5 test your ISO image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) before using it to make a new disc. If that fails, you'll have to download a new ISO image.

If all else fails, please consider using the [text-based Alternate CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) which contains a text-only installer to sidestep any graphics issues.

Comment: Im going to try my 11.10 disk and see if that works.

Comment: okay, i got to the error with the driver, it just skipped it, why does the ubuntu 12.04 just hang there?