# Problems while  installing Ubuntu 12.04 64 & 32 bits from LiveCd

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my new pc but I am encountering problems. When I boot from the installation CD, everything runs fine until the "**window**" when the user has to decide to **Try Ubuntu** or **Install** it in the machine.

Well that "**window**" appears in blank, and  my mouse and keyboard behaves really **slow**. I can't do anything , so i have to shut it down by pressing power button.

The specification of my pc are this

- Motherboard: Gigabyte ex58 ud7
- CPU: i7 950
- HD: Western digital caviar black
- Int. memory: 6gb memory corsair
- Graphics: evga gtx580

I really need to install Ubuntu or another Linux distribution, i am using **de seismic Unix program**  *{Edit :  Guess it is [this](http://www.cwp.mines.edu/cwpcodes/)}* on my laptop. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Try installing from Live Usb Drive.

Comment: sorry but it not works

Comment: Do you have any screenshots ?

Comment: where can a put screenshots?

Comment: Please check the **md5sum** of ISO image of Ubuntu from the Downloaded site , see to it that it matches , or you will have to redownload it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring at the graphical window where you are asked if you want to **Try Ubuntu** or **Install Ubuntu**. Assuming you've [made sure the installation media is good](https://askubuntu.com/a/162025/22949), the next thing you might want to try doing is just *skipping that window altogether*.

If you hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the keyboard and person icons at the bottom of the purple boot screen, you'll get a menu. (This is the same menu where you may have selected "Check disc for defects.")

Select **Try Ubuntu without installing** from that menu. This should give you a desktop, without ever giving you the `ubiquity-dm` window where you are asked graphically to choose.

- There are two ways to choose between **Try Ubuntu** and **Install Ubuntu**. One is graphically--the GUI loads, and gives you the choice in a window. That functionality is provided by a program called `ubiquity-dm`. It looks like the problem might be with that. The other way is to prevent `ubiquity-dm` from ever showing that window, by choosing which you want *before* the GUI loads. That's what you're doing when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select **Try Ubuntu without installing** (or **Install Ubuntu**) from the non-graphical boot menu.

If that works, you can use Ubuntu from the live CD, and you can install it by double-clicking on the **Install Ubuntu** icon on the desktop or in the Unity launcher (the vertical bar on the left side of the screen).

Comment: ok, first i am trying check disc for defect... when it finished i will " try ubuntu without installin" but i cant understand when you said "this should give you a desktop, without ever giving you the ubiquity-dm window where you are asked graphically to choose".

Comment: ok no errors found when i check disc for defects..

Comment: @user76104 I've edited my answer to explain this in greater detail.

Comment: Well I choose try ubuntu without installling and see that the screen freezes. A description of the screen is that it is purple in the middle says ubuntu ubuntu and below there are 5 red dots

Comment: @user76104 When the screen with the dots first comes up, try pressing `Escape` or `F2`. That should reveal what messages are "behind" the splash screen. Then you can edit your question to include them. That should make further troubleshooting possible.

Comment: ok i try pressing escape, and i see some errors like this:
ata id[498]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdc/: invalid argumen

and when the said:
starting restore sound card(s) mixer state.... FAIL

the other thinks are ok

Comment: but i see that there are some one that it is the same i mean.. starting restore sound cars mixers states and it id ok but then apears another an said fail

Comment: ok i try to disable by BIOS de sound card but it doesnt work i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

when your installation start, on main menu, pres F6 and then select first two options(from above), press Esc and continue with your installation.

Comment: when it starts to load the achieve ubuntu environment to enter a menu with a graphical environment but I managed to get something sturdy and gave him to try ubuntu, started to load but freezes on the sign of ubuntu with red spots and only shows me the pointer not more ..... any other option?

ps: had previously tried to install the alternate version of ubuntu not having success: S

Comment: when you put your cd, you'll see icon in bottom center part of screen -> press any key -> select language -> then do what I told you in previous post

Answer (score 0):

> Most often this happens because you have a bad disc. This is
>   especially likely if you've already installed the same version of
>   Ubuntu on this machine before, and didn't have that problem.
>
> The disc could have been damaged, or it could have started out bad
>   (for example, due to a bad ISO image).
>
> - [Check it for defects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161616/ubuntu-install-cd-hangs-at-5-red-dots-while-booting/161998#161998) on the machine you want to install it on. (That way, the disc gets checked, and so does the computer/drive's
>     ability to read it.)
> - If that fails, make sure to [MD5 test your ISO image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161616/ubuntu-install-cd-hangs-at-5-red-dots-while-booting/161998#161998) before using it to make a new disc. If that fails, you'll have to download a
>     new ISO image.
>
> If all else fails, please consider using the [text-based Alternate
>   CD](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) which contains a text-only installer to sidestep any graphics
>   issues.

[Originally posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161616/ubuntu-install-cd-hangs-at-5-red-dots-while-booting/161998#161998) by [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) and [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) (see [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/161998/revisions)).

Comment: Thanks for your response, in addition to the above I have try with the text mode installation and it worked to some extent, if I install the ubuntu 12.04 64 bit but when i try to login it was frozen, then format my disk and perform a clean install of windows. I've also tried with different installers on CD (I tested the 12.04 (32 bit) and I have the same problem. And the last thing and tried to install it from a pen drive getting the same result as when the life instlaod cd ... . Any other suggestions

Comment: While I agree that checking the ISO and installation media for corruption is a good idea here (as it almost always is when there is any installation problem), please note that this is *not* the same situation as in [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161616/ubuntu-install-cd-hangs-at-5-red-dots-while-booting).