# problems with installation of ubuntu 12.04 (64 and 32 bits)

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems while  installing Ubuntu 12.04 64 & 32 bits from LiveCd.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161845/problems-while-installing-ubuntu-12-04-64-32-bits-from-livecd)

I am a latinoamerican so.. sorry for my english I am trying to install ubuntu on my new pc but I have serious problems. When I put the installation cd and it runs, everything goes fine until that "window" when the user have to decide if want to try ubuntu or install it on the machine.. well that "window" apears in blank, and I see that my mouse and my keyboard turn really slowly and I can't do anything I have to shut it down by pressing power botton.

The specification of my pc are this

Gigabyte ex58 ud7 i7 950 wester digital caviar black 6gb memory corsair evga gtx580

Please i really neeed to install ubuntu or another linux distrubution, i am usign de sismic unix program on my laptop and well. it burns when i program a script! help! please :) what can i do..? what i have to download? i am not a pro in linux so please :( be pattient with me

when it starts to load the achieve ubuntu environment to enter a menu with a graphical environment but I managed to get something sturdy and gave him to try ubuntu, started to load but freezes on the sign of ubuntu with red spots and only shows me the pointer not more ..... any other option? ps: had previously tried to install the alternate version of ubuntu not having success: S

Comment: I guess you already this question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161845/problems-with-ubuntu-12-04-64-bits-and-32-bits).Be patient replys and answers will come.