# A Wine v1.61:1.6.3 install locked up about 2/3rds through.

Tags: wine

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu.  I tried to install Wine version above and it locked up and greyed out the install window about 2/3rds through install.  No messages, no warning; just stopped.  Do I need to clean this up/remove the partial install and try again?  If so how should the clean up be done?  Is there a history on this somewhere I can study?

Comment: what method of installation are you using to install wine?

Comment: I just went to the Ubuntu software center, looked up Wine and clicked on the download button.

Comment: When I did that a window opened up called Wine Windows Program Loader.

Comment: can you close the windows?

Comment: Now the little software center app is locked up on this window and I can't do anything with it but a force quit.  Don't want to force quit until I've found an  answer to the problem..

Comment: If I close the window I get a message that says this window has stopped working.  Do you want to force quit?

Comment: I'm concerned that a bunch of code has been installed but not completed, and I want to be able to get all that code out, where ever it may be installed, and then reinstall.  Or would the installer recognize or replace that code if I install again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

force it to quit and then run the following commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall wine
```

Comment: OK thanks.  Maybe problem is solved.  I ran the above steps and the terminal window says Wine was installed unpacked, and set up.  But I see no signs of Wine having been installed from my desk top or the dashboard.  Maybe I need to reboot??

Comment: Also, I have an icon on the dashboard called Install Release.  No other identification.  It was not there before I ran the code you sent me.

Comment: @sodypop http://askubuntu.com/a/338952

Comment: problems resolved.  Wine runs and Install release has been removed.  Thanks mchid for the help.